# mounting smb via ssh tunnel - malformed UNC

Tags: linux, ssh, smbclient

on my Fedora box i want to mount a Windows Server Share via a ssh tunnel. The setup consists of two parts, ssh and mount part.

Part 1.) i do a ssh portforwarding of Port 445 from windows server to my  Fedora box via a linux gateway

```
sudo ssh -C -L 127.0.0.2:445:msserver:445 gatewayuser@gateway.gwdomaine.com
```

that works fine and i can access the Windows Server share on my Fedora box in Filemanager or with smbclient on address smb://127.0.0.2

ok, but i want to use that share via linux filesystem. Therefore i need to mount it

```
sudo mount -t cifs //127.0.0.2 /mnt/smb -o username=domaineuser.msserverdomaine
```

but now the problems occure. It asks me about the domaine password on the MS Server.

```
Password for domaineuser.msserverdomaine@//127.0.0.2:
```

which seems already not like a valid account. And after providing the pwd i got a

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Dmesg shows me

```
[41077.581330] CIFS: VFS: Malformed UNC in devname
[41109.021447] Malformed UNC in devname
```

So, wheres my mistake? It seems clear that mount got's confused with the ssh portforwardimng. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for specifying the domain name is wrong. Try:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //127.0.0.2 /mnt/smb -o username=domaineuser,domain=msserverdomaine
```

Comment: Thank you. You pointed me to the correct and complete solution. What was missing is the ability to write to the mounted share via

sudo mount -t cifs //127.0.0.2 /mnt/smb -o username=domaineuser,domain=msserverdomaine,uid=LinuxUserID,gid=LinuxUserGroupID